# How do I connect to a SQL Server instance of a Windows server from a Linux server using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, sql-server, linux

I have 2 servers. Test A: Linux Ubuntu 14.04 and Test B: Windows Server 2008. Both servers are in the same network.

Test B: The Windows server is running MS SQL Server. I checked the 'TCP/IP enabled' setting; it is running and the port is 143` (IPALL). I confirmed that SQL server browser is running on the server as well. The port is also opened inside the network.

Test A: I'm trying to connect Test B's MSSQL using port 1433 and the private IP of the machine in the network. But I get

> Error creating connection pool { Error: Failed to connect to PRIVATEIP:1433 in 1500ms }

I have one more machine in the same network, Test C, which is a Windows 7 machine. I used SQL Server Management studio and also the same node script, and it is working fine: I'm able to connect to the SQL server with the same code and config.

I'm using Express, MSSQL package to connect to the MSSQL server. I also used "tedious" but encountered the same issue.

```
var express = require("express");
var sql = require("mssql");
var config = require("./config.json");

console.log(config.mssql); // i can see the mssql configs here

var conPool = new sql.ConnectionPool(config.mssql);

var app = express();
var PORT = 8080;

conPool.connect(function(err){
        if(err){
            console.error('Error creating connection pool', err);          
        } else {
            console.log('Connection pool is opened');
            app.use(function (req, res, next) {
            req.cp = conPool;
            next();
        })
        require('./routes')(app);
        app.listen(PORT, function () {
            console.log("Server started in port", PORT);
        })

    }
});
```

The connecting string is below.

```
{
    "mssql": {
        "user": "username",
        "password": "password",
        "server": "10.789.456.123",
        "database": "Database",
        "port": 1433,
        "dialect": "mssql",
        "dialectOptions": {
            "instanceName": "MSSQLEXPRESS"
        },
        "pool": {
            "min": 2,
            "max": 10
        }                             
    }   
}
```

I don't know what I need to do to achieve this.

Comment: did you try `telnet` the port of `mssql` from linux server , if yes are you able to connect to that port ?

Comment: I tried but not able to connect..

Comment: Then it looks like the IP and port is not accessible from your server, try ping the IP, make sure the IP is reachable, are you should the IP is open and visible for you linux server